# Error in call API Json DeserializeObject in controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am getting an error like this when I am trying to get data from another API.

[image: Error Image]

Here is the controller code to call API

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<Author>? AuthorList = new List<Author>();
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/Authors"))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            AuthorList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Author>>(apiResponse);
        }
    }
    return View(AuthorList);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide example json? Error is pretty clear - endpoint returns single object so it can't be deserialized to list.

Comment: Could share your code about the action in API , we need more information so that we can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the error what I could understand is from the API you're getting a JSON object - not a JSON array. And in the code, you're trying to deserialize `apiResponse` which is an `Author` object to `List<Author>`.

Either make changes in the API to return `List<Author>` or deserialize to `Author` instead of `List<Author>`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you shared the replica of JSON too,
From the error, we can probably say that the list you are getting is in a single object... You should try something like this...

```
public class Author
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
public class AuthorObject
{
   public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

and then you should try something like below,

```
AuthorObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthorObject>(apiResponse);
```

It will solve the error.